# Prisma migration needs default value?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, orm, prisma

I'm having a problem with Prisma data modeling give tried almost everything but i still don't get what this error is giving me. It says that table needs a default value when I already have given it a ID then i tried to remove the relation name same thing happens here my model:

```
model UserToUser {
id          Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
userId      Int?
follower    User? @relation("follower",fields: [userId], references: [id])
following   User  @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
followingId Int  
}
```

Then it gives me an error saying "Step 2 Added the required column `followingId` to the `UserToUser` table without a default value. There are 2 rows in this table, it is not possible to execute this step."
How do I fix it?

```
model User {
id              Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
points          Int               @default(0)
email           String            @unique
password        String
name            String?
posts           Post[]
Profile         Profile?
About           About?
Update          Update[]
Liked           Liked[]
following       UserToUser[] @relation("following")
follower        UserToUser[] @relation("follower")
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the User Model

Comment: Yyes , ill edit the question and show you

Comment: How about let Prisma create the Many-to-Many table and just use my example and delete `UserToUser` model

Answer (score 0):

Can you see this example from prisma [Docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations?utm_source=Prisma%20Ambassador&utm_medium=Blog%20post&utm_campaign=Prisma%20AP%20Ahmed%20Hafez%20Elywa)?

```
model User {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String?
  followedBy  User[]   @relation("UserFollows", references: [id])
  following   User[]   @relation("UserFollows", references: [id])
}
```